# How to implement a more flexible AsyncTask?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, ui-thread

while it is very convenient to use, from my understanding, `AsyncTask` has two important limitations:

1. `doInBackground` of any instances will share the same worker
   thread, i.e. one long running `AsyncTasks` can block all others.
2. `execute`, `onPostExecute` and other "synchronizing" methods must/will always be executed on the UI-thread, i.e. not on the Thread, which wants to start the task.

I ran into trouble, when I tried to reuse some existing AsyncTasks in a background `IntentService` that are responsible for the client-server communication of my app. The tasks of the service would fight over time in the worker thread with those of the UI activities. Also they would force the service to fall back onto the UI-thread, although that service should perform its work quietly in the background.

How would I go about removing/circumventing these limitations? I basically want to achieve:

1. A framework that closely resembles AsyncTask (because I need to migrate a lot of critical code there).
2. Each instance of such a task should run its `doInBackground` on its own thread instead of a single worker thread for all instances.

   Edit: Thx to VinceFR for pointing out this can be achieved by simply calling `executeOnExecutor` instead of `execute`.
3. The callbacks like `onPostExecute` should be called on the same thread that started the task by calling `execute`, which should not need to be the UI-thread.

I figure, I'm not the first person to require something like this. Therefore I wonder: Is there already some third-party library that can be recommended to accomplish this? If not, what would be a way to implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/octo-online/robospice. alternative to asynctask

Comment: Thanks, I've dug a little in the documentation. It seems like RoboSplice will call you back on the UI-thread as well. Also the framework won't allow for an easy migration. However, it seems like a really good way for any new code.

Comment: FYI:doInBackground of any instance will NOT sharing the same thread if you use `executeOnExecutor` instead of `execute`(function doc [here][1])


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29

Comment: Thx! Half way there! Changing the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution looks like this:

All classes that spawn `AsyncTask`s that might interfere with each other get their own `Executor` like this one (make that elaborate as you like using thread pools etc.):

```
private Executor serviceExecutor = new Executor() {
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        new Thread(command).start();
    }
};
```

As pointed out by VinceFR you can run an `AsyncTask` on a given `Executor` by calling it like this (where `payload` are the parameters that you would regularly pass to a task):

```
task.executeOnExecutor(serviceExecutor, payload);
```

However, this breaks backwards-compatibility to Gingerbread and earlier. Also, if you want to support Honeycomb, you need to make sure, this call happens on the UI thread. Jelly Bean will take care of this automatically.

Now the trickier part: Keeping the service running on its own thread. As many things in Android this seems harder than it needs to be (or maybe I'm lacking some information here). You can't use an `IntentService`, because that will shut down automatically the first time an `AsyncTask` takes over and let's the `onHandleIntent` callback complete.

You need to setup your own thread and event loop on the service:

```
public class AsyncService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = AsyncService.class.getSimpleName();
private class LooperThread extends Thread {
    public Handler threadHandler = null;

    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        this.threadHandler = new Handler();
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
private LooperThread serviceThread = null;
private Handler serviceThreadHandler = null;

@Override
// This happens on the UI thread
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
// This happens on the UI thread
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    this.serviceThread = new LooperThread();
    this.serviceThread.start();
    while(this.serviceThread.threadHandler == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Waiting for service thread to start...");
    }
    this.serviceThreadHandler = this.serviceThread.threadHandler;
    this.serviceThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doTheFirstThingOnTheServiceThread();
        }
    });
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

// doTheFirstThingOnTheServiceThread

}
```

No you need to make sure that each time an `AsyncTask` returns to the UI thread, you end up in your service thread instead:

```
// This happens on the serviceThread
private void doTheFirstThingOnTheServiceThread() {
    // do some stuff

    // here we can reuse a class that performs some work on an AsyncTask
    ExistingClassWithAsyncOperation someUsefullObject = new ExistingClassWithAsyncOperation();
    // the existing class performs some work on an AsyncTask and reports back via an observer interface
    someUsefullObject.setOnOperationCompleteListener(new OnOperationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        // This happens on the UI thread (due to an ``AsyncTask`` in someUsefullObject ending)
        public void onOperationComplete() {
            serviceThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doTheSecondThingOnTheServiceThread();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    someUsefulObject.performOperation();
}

// This happens on the serviceThread
private void doTheSecondThingOnTheServiceThread() {
    // continue working on the serviceThread
}
```

So, this works for me. I'd be delighted to see a simpler solution for this. Note that the solution requires the service to know that is will be called back by the `ExistingClassWithAsyncOperation` on the UI thread. I don't particularly like this dependency, but don't know how to do better right now. However, I don't have to rewrite a lot of existing classes that perform asynchronous operations using `AsyncTask`.